# How to Store the text fields array data in database without using loop using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ror and I am trying from 4 hours to store the data of form of textfields array like this

```
<input type="text" name="custom_field[names][]" class="form-control full-width" placeholder =  "Name">

<input type="text" name="custom_field[length_limit][]" class="form-control full-width" placeholder =  "Length Limit">
```

I want to store the arrays coming into the form in database columns of name and length limit. I don't want to use loop to do this job.

I am doing this in controller

```
user = CustomField.create(:name=> params[:names])
```

But it is giving `ERROR: null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint DETAI`

params are

```
{"names"=>["tester", "another tester"], "length_limit"=>["aaaaaa222", "aaaaaa222"]
```

I am using postgresql

How can I do this?

Comment: What do your submitted params look like?

Comment: @jvillian I haved added the params in question.

Comment: @jvillian any idea?

Comment: If you really want this then `CustomField.create(:name=> params[:names].to_s)` will convert the `Array` to a `String` for storage. that being said why not use a `postgres` `Array` column instead? [Postgres Data Types Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html)

Comment: `:name` or `:names` ? which is which? can you double-check you haven't just got a typo with one that is pluralised and one that isn't? (Note: according to the ruby way you should call them all `names` because there's more than one of them).

Answer (score 0):

`params[:names]` is an array, so it doesn't make sense to save it to a string/text field in postgres, which is what `CustomField.create(:name=> params[:names])` does.

Essentially, it expands to `CustomField.create(:name=> ["tester", "another tester"])`. If you want to create a separate CustomField record for each name, then you could do something like:

```
params[:names].each do |name|
  CustomField.create(:name => name)
end
```

To create the CustomField records with the corresponding `length_limit`, you could do something like:

```
params[:names].zip(params[:length_limit]).each do |name, limit|
  CustomField.create(:name => name, :length_limit => limit)
end
```

Note that this doesn't account for errors where the `name`s and `length_limit`s don't match. You might want to add some validation to make sure that all the required data is present.